# Trouble With Simple Custom Keras Metric Function Can't Return Argmax?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'd like to create a custom metric and I've learned that within a custom function everything is a tensor and I need to use the special backend functions. To wrap my head around this I tried a three class classification problem example where I simply return the argmax as the custom function

```
def custom(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.argmax(y_pred)

# Neural Network
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(len(np.unique(X.values)), 4)) 
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy', custom])

model.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values, epochs=4)
```

To my surprise I'm getting floating point values in the output!

```
Epoch 1/4
1023/1023 [==============================] - 0s 276us/step - loss: 0.3560 - acc: 0.3294 - custom: 1.1867
Epoch 2/4
1023/1023 [==============================] - 0s 52us/step - loss: 0.3368 - acc: 0.3343 - custom: 1.9687
Epoch 3/4
1023/1023 [==============================] - 0s 47us/step - loss: 0.3225 - acc: 0.3324 - custom: 1.9374
Epoch 4/4
1023/1023 [==============================] - 0s 47us/step - loss: 0.3173 - acc: 0.3275 - custom: 1.2825
```

This clearly isn't doing what I expected and I don't know why

**Question: Why is my custom metric that just returns the argmax not returning an integer vector that represents the argmax's and instead is returning a floating point number?**

PS: I modified the custom function to print

```
def custom(y_true, y_pred):
    x = K.argmax(y_pred)
    x = K.print_tensor(x, message="x is: ")
    return(x)
```

and I get output like this

```
Epoch 4/4
x is: [2 2 0...]
  32/1023 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3113 - acc: 0.2500 - custom: 1.0000x is: [2 0 0...]
x is: [0 0 0...]
x is: [0 0 0...]
x is: [2 0 2...]
```

Which again isn't making any sense to me. Does anyone know what's happening under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

argmax function is working correctly. For each batch argmax is returning an integer. But the output of the metric function for the whole batch will be mean of the batch.
Keras [documentation](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.0/metrics/) says

> Returns
>   Single tensor value representing the mean of the output array across
>   all datapoints.

So if your custom metric function is returning some arrays of class values for certain batch, the model will calculate the average of these values.