# confused over y_true and y_pred when using keras custom metrics

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have a classification problem between 2 classes; 0 and 1. I am trying to learn keras custom metrics involving confusion matrix, I would expect this function

```
from keras import backend as K

def positives(y_true,y_pred):
    return K.sum(y_true)
```

to return an int equivalent to `np.sum(y_test)` which is 21 but `positives` returns 2.667.

```
model.compile(
    keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=[positives])
```

I am using tensorflow backend

even when using off the shelf sensitivity, specificity... metrics from stackoverflow i get different answers than `sklearn.metrics.classification_report` on the final epoch.

Comment: This could be because of the output is averaged over the batch. Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53817520/5825953) answer

Comment: @Carl what was your batch size.?

Comment: thank you both, accounting for batch size solves the issue.